# Finding the mean of each key in a dataframe using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a list of beer types and a list of ratings. There are duplicates, so each beer type has multiple ratings. I made them into tuples:

```
merge = zip(types, ratings)
```

I'm trying to find the mean rating for each beer type. I tried to make the tuples into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([merge])
```

but I didn't know what to put in the groupby parameter.
I tried this too:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Ratings': [ratings], 'Types':[types]})
df.groupby('Types').mean()
```

but it doesn't work either. What parameter would I put into groupby to make this work? Or is using groupby not the way to go?

Comment: Sorry about that. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.from_records`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(merge, columns=['types', 'ratings'])
```

If `ratings` is not a numeric type, convert it using `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df.ratings = pd.to_numeric(df.ratings, errors='coerce')
```

Next, `groupby` on `types` and find the `mean`:

```
g = df.groupby('types').ratings.mean()
print(g)
```